# SQL subquery getting error or comparing the whole table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have three tables (`b_j`, `b_j_h_s` and `m_w_j`) with timestamps columns and I want to compare the dates from them.
`b_j` and `b_j_h_s` relation is 1:N. I'm expecting getting the `member_id`s if any of the `member_id` falls under four comparisons.

The comparisons:

```
(DATEDIFF(m_w_j.created_at, b_j.created_at) < 40 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), (SELECT MIN(b_j_h_s.created_at) FROM b_j_h_s)) < 40)
(DATEDIFF(m_w_j.created_at, b_j.created_at) < 40 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), (SELECT MIN(b_j_h_s.created_at) FROM b_j_h_s)) > 40)
(DATEDIFF(m_w_j.created_at, b_j.created_at) > 40 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), (SELECT MIN(b_j_h_s.created_at) FROM b_j_h_s)) < 40)
(DATEDIFF(m_w_j.created_at, b_j.created_at) > 40 AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), (SELECT MIN(b_j_h_s.created_at) FROM b_j_h_s)) > 40)
```

I'm expcting to get something like this:

```
| member_id | h_s_count | h_s_status |
|     1     |     5     |     4      |
|     3     |     8     |     3      |
```

but I`m getting nothing in return.

Here's my query

```
select b_j.member_id as member_id,
    COUNT(b_j_h_s.id) as h_s_count,
    CAST(IFNULL(SUM(b_j_h_s.status), 0) as UNSIGNED) as h_s_status
from `b_j`
inner join `b_j_h_s` on `b_j`.`id` = `b_j_h_s`.`b_j_id`
inner join `m_w` on `b_j`.`member_id` = `m_w`.`member_id`
inner join `m_j` on `m_j`.`member_id` = `b_j`.`member_id` and `m_j`.`j_id` = 4
inner join `m_w_j` on `m_w_j`.`m_j_id` = `m_j`.`id` and `m_w_j`.`m_w_id` = `m_w`.`id`
where (`b_j`.`b_s_id` in (1, 2)
    and `b_j`.`deleted_at` is null
    and (DATEDIFF(m_w_j.created_at, b_j.created_at) < 40
        AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), (SELECT MIN(b_j_h_s.created_at) FROM b_j_h_s)) > 40)
    or (DATEDIFF(m_w_j.created_at, b_j.created_at) > 40
        AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), (SELECT MIN(b_j_h_s.created_at) FROM b_j_h_s)) > 40)
    or (DATEDIFF(m_w_j.created_at, b_j.created_at) < 40
        AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), (SELECT MIN(b_j_h_s.created_at) FROM b_j_h_s)) < 40)
    or (DATEDIFF(m_w_j.created_at, b_j.created_at) > 40
        AND DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), (SELECT MIN(b_j_h_s.created_at) FROM b_j_h_s)) < 40))       
group by `member_id`
having h_s_count != h_s_status
```

My thoughts was that in the fragment `DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), select min(b_j_h_s.created_at) from b_j_h_s)`, the `b_j_h_s.created_at` was one related to an specific `member_id`, but I'm thinking that the query is using the `min(b_j_h_s.created_at)` from the whole table instead.

[fiddle to test](https://dbfiddle.uk/m5QWpQgB)

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. Put all & only what is needed to ask in your post, not just at a link.

Comment: There is no question in this post. PS Answers belong in answer posts & not in question posts. You can post your own answer & accept after minimal wait. [answer] PS Put all & only what is needed to ask in your post, not just at a link. PS It is good practice & extremely helpful to always use a tiny mnemonic alias for every table used in a join & for every mention of a column from one. PS Please avoid social & meta commentary in posts.

Answer (score 0):

Every `DATEDIFF` that expects to return the difference between the current date and the minimum date from `b_j_h_s` has an issue.

`DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), select min(b_j_h_s.created_at) as b_j_h_s_created_at)` should be something like :

```
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), (select min(b_j_h_s.created_at) from b_j_h_s) )
```

Additionally, several tables and columns in your fiddle are missing. Consider revising the query I'm sharing in my demo because I deleted them from it.

[Here is my demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/OWGvmSEC)